# Battleship AI - completely lost

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building a Battleship game using C#.NET. It's supposed to use a fairly simple scoring mechanism. No ship sinking, if either the player or the computer scores 17 hits, they win. If you score a hit, you get to take another turn. The AI attacks randomly until it scores a hit, at which point it will attack a tile in each direction until it finds a trend, then continue attacking in a straight line until it finds a dead end (either an unoccupied space or an edge of the board. If there were spaces that hadn't been hit in the opposite direction that the computer had been attacking, it will then attack those spaces. It does not target spaces it has already hit or follow patterns that have already been followed.

Here's my AI thus far.

```
    int shipCounter = 0, trend = 0;
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    bool gameOver = false, playerTurn = false;
    int[] score = { 0, 0 };

    struct gameData
    {
        public bool occupied, hit, marked;
    }
    gameData[,,] data;



    public void computerMove()
    {
        Point target = seekTarget();

        try
        {
            if (data[1, target.X, target.Y].hit)
                computerMove();
            else
            {
                data[1, target.X, target.Y].hit = true;
                if (data[1, target.X, target.Y].occupied)
                {
                    attacking = true;
                    score[0]++;
                    computerMove();
                }
            }

            playerTurn = true;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        { computerMove(); }
    }

    public Point seekTarget()
    {
        Point origin = new Point(-1, -1);

        //find a point that's been hit.
        int x = 0, y = 0;

        while (x < gridSize && y < gridSize)
        {
            if (data[1, x, y].hit && data[1, x, y].occupied && !data[1, x, y].marked)
            {
                origin = new Point(x, y);
                break;
            }
            x++;
            if (x == gridSize && y != gridSize)
            {
                x = 0;
                y++;
            }
        }

        return findTargets(origin);            
    }

    public Point findTargets(Point origin) 
    {
        Point[] lim = { origin, origin, origin, origin };
        Point[] possibleTargets = { origin, origin, origin, origin };

        //Find the edges.

        while (lim[0].X >= -1 && ((!data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].hit && !data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].occupied) || (data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].hit && data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].occupied)))
        {
            lim[0].X--;
            if (lim[0].X == -1)
                break;
        }
        while (lim[1].Y >= -1 && ((!data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].hit && !data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].occupied) || (data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].hit && data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].occupied)))
        {
            lim[1].Y--;
            if (lim[1].Y == -1)
                break;
        }
        while (lim[2].X <= gridSize && ((!data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].hit && !data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].occupied) || (data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].hit && data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].occupied)))
        {
            lim[2].X++;
            if (lim[2].X == gridSize)
                break;
        }
        while (lim[3].Y <= gridSize && ((!data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].hit && !data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].occupied) || (data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].hit && data[1, lim[0].X, lim[0].Y].occupied)))
        {
            lim[3].Y++;
            if (lim[3].Y == gridSize)
                break;
        }

        //Cell targeting AI

        }
        return new Point(rnd.Next(10), rnd.Next(10));
    }
```

It's gotten extremely messy due to my inability to figure out what's going wrong. If I quote out the `findTargets` function and just have the computer attack randomly, it works fine. The computer and player trade turns and the computer hits register.

With `findTargets` enabled, however, the player can make one attack and the computer never takes its turn. It then does not revert to the player turn, even though the player's attack crosshairs are still visible. If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated. Apologies for not including the `Paint` or `mouseDown` methods, they exceeded the character limits.

UI without `findTargets` (player and computer trade turns).
[image]

UI with `findTargets` (computer cannot take turn, player only takes one turn).
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** I've isolated the problem, it seems that it can't break out of the while loops in `findTargets`. Even if I address the problem by stopping it from looping when `origin` is `(-1, -1)`, it gets caught in the loop on the first hit.

**EDIT 2:** It's hitting the first loop, and looping infinitely. For some reason, it isn't incrementing `lim[0].X` at all. When I insert a messagebox into the loop to display some data, it displays twice and then does not reappear, even though it is still looping. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Separate your presentation and logic.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Best Comment Ever.

Comment: Are you sure you've presented us with enough code? Could we get the png's too?

Comment: You've got a lot of copy/pasted code, try to refactor it, it will help you a lot

Comment: You should look at this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem
and then write another algorithm. Just an advise

Comment: Step 1 is going to be to put a breakpoint at the top of findTargets and step through it after the first player turn.  That should tell you exactly where it is getting hung up.

Comment: I'm guessing your code is getting stuck within a while loop... Chris Livelys comment above is your best bet

Comment: @Sayse Just tested it -- that's exactly what's happening. Because it loops even if the point is `(-1, -1)`. I fixed that, but now it's looping forever when it finds a target. Going to find out why.

Comment: Of course it's confusing--As you glance over your code you should see 3 sections of repetition--You can often tell repeted code just by examining the structure of your code.  If you start to use well-named methods to delegate some of this work and possibly a few more classes you will find a lot of problems go away. I think there is a refactoring stack-overflow site, I'd give this to them and see what they come up with.  Once it's laid out correctly and properly factored you'll be surprised how easy it will be to fix your problem and how much faster and easier your work will be.

Comment: Closed as too localized? Why is it a sin to ask for help to solve your OWN problem? By those standards most questions in SO nowadays should be closed as too localized...

Answer (score 3):

You are using an object oriented language - looks like Java to me.

So, to make it easier to code, easier to understand, easier to maintain, easier to enhance your code, try using some actual objects.

For example, you should definitely have a Ship class, definitely should have a Grid class, probably a Shot class, etc.  Your Ship class should definitely "plug-in" to your Grid class.  Your Grid class SHOULD NOT allocate the entire grid of potential locations, rather it should only allocate valid Hit areas because a Ship instance is plugged into them.  Every location not inhabited by a Ship instance is obviously a miss, so handle all locations not containing a ship in a single method -

The Grid class is going to do all the work - it could have a addShipHorizontal(Ship, x, y), an addShipVertical(Ship, x, y).  It should definitely have a hitTest(x, y) which returns either null or a Ship.  It should maintain a collection of Ship instances, like ArrayList, which it will iterate over within the hitTest(x, y) method.

Ship should have a PointCount and a collection of Points, which get set when the ship is passed into the addShipH() or addShipV() methods. Ship should also have a hitTest(x, y) method, which returns a true if the ship is inhabiting the specified x, y.  hitTest(x, y) will iterate through the ships collection of Points looking for a match.

When its time to take a shot, pick your location on the grid and hit test it - does the chosen location contain a Ship reference, yes, then do a ship.hit(location) and return a new Hit() - otherwise return a new Miss();

Break it down into the objects you actually think about simulating - this is called a domain model.   Then give each object class the appropriate methods so that the actual game is merely an orchestration amongst and between the domain model classes.

Don't write the game code - instead, write the classes, then the methods of the classes - as you build up the classes the game will arise out of the interaction between the classes via their methods.

Starting from the top, what class will you need 2 instances of at the top of the application?  Answer - Player.  What does a Player class manage?  A Grid and a list of Ships.  What does a Grid manage?  The list of Ships and their locations, and Hit testing for Shots.  What does a Ship maintain?  Its location on the Grid and which of the locations it is positioned in have/have not been hit.

You will find if you do it OO style, it will be 1/4 the code and have twice the flexibility.  Good luck!

Comment: I wish I could, but the rules of my assignment are that it is to be kept classless. This should have been done days ago.

Comment: @user1576628 really classless? I hope there is a really good reason.

Comment: If your instructor is asking it be done classless, I would drop the class.  Classless would be the equivalent of structured programming, ala C in the early 1980's.  Object orientation was created to address deficiencies in structured programming and is the current standard in the industry (although you couldn't tell that by looking at the code for most major systems today)Classless would be Object Orientation was created to address structured programming deficiencies, which is what classless would be.  Also, if you're using java, it can't, by definition, ever be classless.

Answer (score 1):

As the @jorge-Chibante mentioned, please, separate your domain code and your presentation code and try to write some unit tests to validate how you expect your AI should behavior, then develop your AI.

In Ships N' Battles, a battleship game, I have built the AI using probability and making a brain map of probability of every square to have a enemy ship. Everything with some tests to help to validate the behaviour and any futures refactorings.

Keep every part of your code with only one responsibility and you'll make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

### AI

In battleship there are 3 different mode of strategy (I'm simplifying here).

- Bomb a random square
- Bomb in a circle
- Bomb in a straight line

At the beginning the computer just need to find a random square that hasn't already been bombed. When he find a square then he need to bomb around it to try and figure out where the ship is. After that he assume this is the ship direction and bomb in a straight line (on both side).

You're computer should have a variable indicating in which mode he is.

### Code

You're code is all over the place, it difficult to read it. You should seperate your logic in more functions. This way it's easier to test/read and figure out where the problem is. Also make sure you're game logic and UI logic are well seperated.

```
public bool IsOccuped(Point target)
public bool AlreadyBombed(Point target)
public bool BombLocation(Point target)
public Point FindNewTarget()
```

Your computer move would then be a lot nicer

```
public void ComputerMove()
{
    Point target;

    target = FindNewTarget();

    BombLocation(target);
}

// There are more efficient way of doing this but it's an example.
public Point FindNewTarget()
{
    Point newTarget = new Point();

    do
    {
        newTarget.x = [get random location from 0 to grid width]
        newTarget.y = [get random location from 0 to grid height]   
    }while(AlreadyBombed(newTarget))
}
```

Even if a function is small, the redability of the code can help a lot.

```
public bool IsOccuped(Point target)
{
    return data[1, target.X, target.Y].hit;
}
```